# Flat list re-rendering when state change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-native-flatlist, mobx

this is my component when the liked state change imported from mobx, the function `handleLikeSubject` takes time to finish the execution due to the re-render of the FlatList, how can I get rid of the re-render?

This is the code of the parent component:

```js
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import { I18nContext } from "../../Context/I18nContext";
import { authStore } from "../../MobX/AuthStore";
import useFetch from "../../ReusbaleTools/Functions/UseFetch";
import Loading from "../../ReusbaleTools/Components/Loading";
import FavSubject from "../../Components/FavSubject";
import { likedSubjectStore } from "../../MobX/LikedSubjectsStore";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const Intro = observer(() => {
  const { i18n } = useContext(I18nContext);

  const { liked, setLikedSubjects, loading } = likedSubjectStore;

  const { userInfo } = authStore;

  const { data, isLoading } = useFetch("get_firstrun_subjects_new", {
    user_id: `${userInfo.ID}`,
  });

  const renderItems = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => {
      const isLiked = liked.some((likedSubject) => likedSubject.ID === item.ID);

      return (
        <FavSubject
          {...item}
          key={item.key}
          liked={isLiked}
          onPress={() => handleLikeSubject(item, isLiked)}
        />
      );
    },
    [liked, handleLikeSubject]
  );

  const subjects = data && data?.subjects;

  const handleLikeSubject = (subject, isLiked) => {
    let updatedLikedSubjects;

    if (isLiked) {
      // If already liked, unlike it
      updatedLikedSubjects = liked.filter((id) => id.ID !== subject.ID);
    } else {
      // If not liked, like it
      updatedLikedSubjects = [subject, ...likedSubjectStore.liked];
    }

    setLikedSubjects(updatedLikedSubjects);
  };

  if (isLoading || loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <View className="flex-1">
      <Text className="p-3 text-[20px] text-center font-regular bg-white">
        {i18n.t("intro.choose")}
      </Text>

      <View className="pt-5 flex-1">
        {subjects && (
          <FlatList
            data={subjects}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.ID}
            renderItem={renderItems}
            numColumns={2}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

export default Intro;
```

This one for the children:

```js
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { memo, useCallback } from "react";

const FavSubject = memo(({ onPress, title, liked }) => {
  const memoizedOnPress = useCallback(onPress, [onPress]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={memoizedOnPress}>
      <View
        className="flex-row items-center bg-white w-[160px] h-[60px] mx-4 mb-5"
        style={[
          styles.card,
          {
            backgroundColor: !liked ? "#ECEDF1" : "white",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <MaterialIcons name="arrow-right" size={34} color="#666666" />
        <Text className="text-base font-regular max-w-[130px] text-center">
          {title}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

export default FavSubject;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 4,
  },
});
```

I tried with useCallback with dependecies and without dependecies and nothing changed.